# What is the difference between r'' and r'^$' in regex for Django URLs?

Tags: python, regex, django

I have a urls.py file that has a line like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('', 
    url(r'', include('my_module.urls'))
)
```

Why is it that when I change the middle line to `url(r'^$', include('my_module.urls'))` it doesn't work?

Isn't this regex for the same (blank) value?

Comment: Have you looked at https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever Django encounters `include()` (`django.conf.urls.include()`), it chops off whatever part of the URL matched up to that point and sends the remaining string to the included URLconf for further processing. But `$` means the URL ends here, so it does not have any thing to chop off and send after `$`.

For more info click [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/urls/#django.conf.urls.include)

Comment: Thanks - is the best way to write this line using `url(r''...` or `url(r'^'...`?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not a Django problem, it's a regex problem.

`r''` is an empty string, it matches every string.

Since `^` matches the beginning of a string and `$` matches the end of a string, so `r'^$'` matches only empty string.

```
>>> re.match(r'', 'abc123')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x1003c4920>
>>> re.match(r'', '')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x1003c4988>
>>> re.match(r'^$', 'abc123')
>>> re.match(r'^$', '')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x1003c4920>
```